# Redirect to referer after post in CreateView in django

Tags: python, django

I have defined a CreateView in django I want to redirect to the referer of that view if that referer contants ‘center’. The idea is like “iredirect the page that brought you to the CreateView if that page’s path contains ‘center’”

I am trying with the following code but is not working since self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') is returning the path of the same createView

```
class CompanyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = CompanyModel
    context_object_name = 'company'
    template_name = 'riesgo/company/company_form.html'
    form_class = CompanyForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST' and "_continue" in self.request.POST:
            return reverse('riesgo:company_update', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
        elif 'center' self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/'):
          # here I want to redirect to page that brought you to the createview of the company
        
        else:
            return reverse_lazy("riesgo:company_detail", kwargs={"pk":self.object.id})
```

Comment: That is because `HTTP_REFERER` has the same path, since before the POST request to this view there was a GET request to the same url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.path property. Read more about it here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path